# GeoServer Slowly Requests to Remote DB

Tags: geoserver

I need someone who's good at GeoServer & Networks to help me figure out what I'm missing here.

I have two servers, one for database (S1) and the other one for my web app & GeoServer (S2). Both inside network A.
Application works fine on S2. Retrieving WMS and GWC layers from S1 through GeoServer [http://privateIP:8081/geoserver/wms] and [http://privateIP:8081/geoserver/gwc/service/wms]

Now, I would like to take S2 out of Network A. So I disconnected it and plugged it again to a 4G internet modem. Then changed GeoServer stores IP addresses to public IP of S1, and Layers requests to the public IP address as well: [http://publicIP:8081/geoserver/wms] and and [http://publicIP:8081/geoserver/gwc/service/wms]

At this point, requesting layers became so unbelievably slow. I can see few tiles of the layers but it takes too long to load then failed with no result but pink tiles.

I couldn't figure out what causes this. Is it rough for GeoServer to request from a remote database? and what is the suggested solution in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are asking GeoServer to pull all of the vector data needed to draw the map (which could be a lot) over a slow network for every tile it draws. This is unlikely to ever be fast enough to be useable.

If this was me I would set up a system something like:

```
DBServer
GeoServer 
GeoWebCache

Network

cascading GeoServer
GeoWebCache
Users
```

To avoid sending too much data over the 4G link.

Comment: So you agree it's because of the remote requesting? since 4G modem can load the internal layers fast enough.

Comment: I'd appreciate some more details on your suggested structure. DBServer and GeoServer and GeoWebCache would be in Network A. then Cascading GeoServer and GeoWebcache and Users with be in Network B. How I'm going to link these two networks?

Comment: isn't the 4G link to connect the two machines?

Comment: I see. so users will be retrieving cascading GeoServer, not the main one. right?

Comment: yes then you get the benefit of caches at both ends

Comment: I'm going to try it, Tanks a lot!